# Change css disabled button

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

The problem is that the "button" is disabled, a frame is applied by the CSS around the icon. How can I change the css ".disable" to avoid applying the frame. I would like to create a new class `.disable`, because when I disable the buttons this css is fine.

```
<button class="btn btn-icon button-transparent" (click)="deleteItem()" [disabled]=user.readOnly><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 5):

As you are using `disabled` attribute on button, you can also give styling to the button which is disabled. So you don't have to add one more condition to just add disabled class.

```
<button class="btn btn-icon button-transparent" 
    [disabled]="user.readOnly" 
    (click)="deleteItem()"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

CSS

```
button:disabled{
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding the class with a condition, see this:

```
<button class="btn btn-icon button-transparent" 
        [class.disabled]="user.readOnly" 
        (click)="deleteItem()" 
        [disabled]=user.readOnly><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```